# Proving $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}\right)$ is irrational where $p\geqslant3$ is prime

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, irrational-numbers

Now I have proven that $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}\right)$ is irrational by taking $\left(x^2-2x\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}\right) +1\right)$ as the minimal polynomial dividing $\frac{(x^p-1)}{(x-1)}\cdots 1$ and then using *Eisentiens irreducibility criteria* to show that $(1)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$ .So I wanted to ask can someone help me to find a similar polynomial where $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}\right)$is replaced by $\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{p}\right)$.

Comment: First of all, $(x^p-1)/(x-1)$ is *not* irreducible when $p > 2$! Also, if you know Galois theory then you can view $\sin(2\pi/p)$ inside the field $\mathbf Q(e^{2\pi i/p},i)$ and find an element of the Galois group of this field over $\mathbf Q$ that does not fix $\sin(2\pi/p)$ as a way of proving that number is not in $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: Are you saying that  $(x^2-2xcos(\frac{2\pi}{p}) +1)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\cos\frac{2\pi}{p}$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  No, the OP is writing in a confusing way; what is meant is that the minimal polynomial of $e^{2\pi i/p}$ over $\mathbf Q$ has degree $p-1$ (not degree $p$ as written!), so that monic quadratic polynomial over $\mathbf Q$ with $e^{2\pi i/p}$ as a root can't have all rational coefficients.

Comment: @smita I would suggest that you rewrite carefully your question. That will help us... and therefore yourself!

Comment: I think @KCd it is irreducible using eisentiens criteria and replacing x by x+1 when $p$ is a prime

Comment: @mathcounterexample.net Sorry for using the term minimal polynomial. It was just by intuition that I came across the polynomial. Any help on how to replace cos by sin .

Comment: @smita  yes, I had misread things.  The ratio $(x^p-1)/(x-1)$ is indeed irreducible over $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: @KCd going by your method, can you be a bit more precise by what it means to not fix sin($\frac{2\pi}{p}$) .Also I am very new to galois thoery , if you could break it up and tell me what all I have to prove . Is the result going to give me a polynomial similar to $(1)$ ? And can I use the similar method.

Comment: When you learn Galois theory you'll know what I meant.  In principle it will lead to a polynomial, but you need to get beyond the idea of seeking out explicit polynomials all the time to figure out if something is or is not in the base field.  That's part of learning Galois theory.  The details are too much for me to explain here.

Answer (score 7):

It would be easy if you know the facts that

- the sum and product of two algebraic integers are again algebraic integers;
- $\Bbb Q$ is integrally closed, i.e. the only algebraic integers in $\Bbb Q$ are the integers, $\Bbb Z$.

Using these two facts, we write $2\sin(\frac{2\pi}p) = -i(e^{\frac{2\pi i}p} - e^{-\frac{2 \pi i}p})$, which shows that it is an algebraic integer.

If it is also rational, then it must be an integer. But $2\sin(\frac{2\pi}p)$ lies between $-2$ and $2$, leaving only $5$ possible values.

Comment: And thus the only rationals $r$ such that $\sin(r \pi)$ is rational are those for which it is $0$, $\pm 1$ or $\pm 1/2$: [Niven's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem)